# querying the database from view web2py

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

I am trying to query a database table from the view in web2py as I need to take a field from another table for each row in the present table so I have written a code like this:

```
{{for recipe in rows:}}

<div class="well">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             <div style="text-align:center">
<img width="200px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=db(db.uploads.recipe_id==recipe.id).select().first().up_file)}}" />
</div>

            </td>
            <td><button>
            -
            </button></td><td><span class='votes'>{{=recipe.votes}}</span></td><td><button>
            +
            </button><td><strong>{{=A("comments",_href=URL('view_posts',args=recipe.id))}},{{=recipe.name}}</strong></td></td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
{{pass}}
```

but I have a doubt whether we could query a database from a view or not?
If not how could I query the same from the controller and return it to the view?
This may be a silly doubt,but sorry I am new to web2py

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do that, but it is not very efficient, as you will have a separate query for each row in the table. Instead, your query to create the `rows` object in the controller should involve a join with the `db.uploads` table:

```
    rows = db((your_current_query) & (db.uploads.recipe == db.recipe.id)).select()
```

Then in the view:

```
{{for row in rows:}}

<div class="well">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             <div style="text-align:center">
<img width="200px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=row.uploads.up_file)}}" />
</div>

            </td>
            <td><button>
            -
            </button></td><td><span class='votes'>{{=row.recipe.votes}}</span></td><td><button>
            +
            </button><td><strong>{{=A("comments",_href=URL('view_posts',args=row.recipe.id))}},{{=row.recipe.name}}</strong></td></td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
{{pass}}
```

Note, because the `rows` object now represents a join between two tables, you must use both the table name and the field name to access a given value (e.g., `row.recipe.name` rather than `row.name`). To make that clear, in the `for` loop, I changed `recipe` to `row`.